# Pass an object from form to another in VB

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have searched through the internet and couldn't find the answer to my problem, but, the issue is that I have 2 forms;

> frm_bookManeger

and

> frm_addBook

The first one is the main form and has a list of books (named `listBook`), a `TreeView` and a button to invoke the second form to add a new book.

After filling in all of the `TextBoxes` and information of a book, I press "Add". Then, the second form will be closed and all info of that book will be kept in an instance of `Book` class. The problem is: how can I pass this instance to the first form to store it in `listBook`.

For example:
If I create a constructor in form 1 to get form 2 then in form 2:

```vb
Dim f1 As form1 = New form1(me)
f1.Show()
f2.Close()
```

I can't do it because form 1 will start up instantly when I start program, and the default right now doesn't have any parameter in OnCreateMainForm():

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
        Me.MainForm = Global.WindowsApplication5.frm1
    End Sub
```

How can I do it?

**First form:**

```vb
Public Class frm_bookManeger

'list of Book
Dim listBook As List(Of Book) = New List(Of Book)

Private frm_addBook As frm_addBook

Public Sub New(frm_addBook As frm_addBook) 'got error
    Me.frm_addBook = frm_addBook
End Sub
```

**Second form:**

```vb
Public Class frm_addBook

Dim Public tempBook As Book = New Book()

'add book
Private Sub btn_add_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_add.Click
    tempBook.BookName1 = TextBox_name.Text
    tempBook.Author1 = TextBox_author.Text
    tempBook.Price1 = TextBox_price.Text
    tempBook.Genre1 = TextBox_genre.Text
    tempBook.EstablishedDay1 = dtp_established.Value.Date
    Dim frm_Mngr As frm_bookManeger = New frm_bookManeger(Me)
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dim frm As New form1
  frm.textbox.Text = Me.passing value.Text 
  frm.Show()
```

or you can try

```
Public Class Form1
Private loginLabel As String

Public Sub New(ByVal loginParameter As String)
     InitializeComponent()

     Me.loginLabel = loginParameter

End Sub
 End Class

dim frm as new Form1(label.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `frm_addBook` needs a reference to the instance of `frm_bookManeger` so that it can use methods in the latter.

That can be done by passing a reference to the current instance of `frm_bookManeger` to the `New` constructor of `frm_addBook`.

Also, you probably want the book adding form to be a dialog form rather than an ordinary form.

I made a simple "Book" class and used a TextBox to display the books, so the first form is this:

```
Imports System.Text

Public Class frm_BookManager

    Dim bookList As List(Of Book)

    Public Class Book
        Property Name As String
        Property Author As String
    End Class

    Public Sub AddBook(b As Book)
        If bookList Is Nothing Then
            bookList = New List(Of Book)
        End If
        bookList.Add(b)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ShowBooks()
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        For Each b In bookList
            sb.AppendLine(b.Name & " by " & b.Author)
        Next

        TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_add_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_add.Click
        Using addBook As New frm_addBook(Me)
            Dim result = addBook.ShowDialog()
            If result = DialogResult.OK Then
                ShowBooks()
            End If
        End Using

    End Sub

    Private Sub frm_BookManager_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddBook(New Book With {.Name = "Wuthering Heights", .Author = "Emily Brontë"})
        ShowBooks()

    End Sub

End Class
```

For the form to add a book, I added "Cancel" and "OK" buttons.

```
Public Class frm_addBook

    Dim myParent As frm_BookManager

    Private Sub bnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnOK.Click
        Dim b As New frm_BookManager.Book With {.Name = TextBox_name.Text, .Author = TextBox_author.Text}
        myParent.AddBook(b)

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(parent As frm_BookManager)

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        myParent = parent

        ' set the DialogResult for each button so the parent can tell what happened
        bnCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
        bnOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK

    End Sub

End Class
```

Notice that a new `Book` can be added with `myParent.AddBook(b)` because `myParent` refers to an instance of `frm_BookManager`.

You could modify it so that the dialog stays open and has a button to just add a book and *not* close the dialog. I made the `ShowBooks()` method Private so you can't call it from outside the class it is in - you could modify that.

There are *many* possibilities for small modifications to the code I showed to achieve greater functionality. And I could not resist correcting the spelling of "Maneger" to "Manager" ;)

Comment: Be advised that you are not disposing of the `frm_addBook` form.  You should probably create it within a `Using...End Using` block.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Thanks. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to have the `frm_addBook` form have a property which will contain the book that was added.  In the `frm_bookManager` form, show that form using `ShowDialog` and if the user clicks OK on that form, the property will contain the book added.  Be sure to dispose the `frm_addBook` form after you get the book from the public property.

```
Public Class Book
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Author As String
End Class

Public Class frm_bookManager

    Dim bookList As New List(Of Book)()

    Private Sub btnAddBook_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddBook.Click
        Using addBookForm As New frm_addBook()
            If addBookForm.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                bookList.Add(addBookForm.BookToAdd)
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class frm_addBook
    Public Property BookToAdd As Book

    Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
        'User filled in the fields and clicked this OK button
        Me.BookToAdd = New Book()
        Me.BookToAdd.Name = txtName.Text
        Me.BookToAdd.Author = txtAuthor.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

I would not pass the main form instance into the add book form because it would create a tight coupling between the two forms and the add book form would only be usable by the main form.  You might wish to use the add book form from other forms in the app.